# Project reactor limitRate operator unexplained behavior

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a relatively simple task - I have records in a database that need to be processed sequentially and synchronously. Each record has a timestamp column which indicates the last processing time. The basic idea was to use a synchronous flux sink to fetch db batches and emit them one by one and use concatMap downstream to do the sequential processing. I have managed to implement this however I see an unexplained behavior so maybe someone could shed light.

Here is an example:

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);

Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.generate((SynchronousSink<Integer> synchronousSink) -> {
   synchronousSink.next(atomicInteger.getAndIncrement());
})
.log()
.take(5)
.limitRate(1)
.concatMap(integer -> Mono.just(integer * 2).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
.doOnNext(integer -> log.debug("x2: {}", integer));

StepVerifier.create(integerFlux)
      .expectNext(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
      .verifyComplete();
```

And the result:

```
10:03:06.442 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
10:03:06.504 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxGenerate.GenerateSubscription)
10:03:06.512 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | request(1)
10:03:06.512 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | onNext(1)
10:03:06.513 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | request(1)
10:03:06.572 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | onNext(2)
10:03:08.584 [parallel-1] DEBUG com.DummyTest - x2: 2
10:03:08.584 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | request(1)
10:03:08.584 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | onNext(3)
10:03:10.588 [parallel-2] DEBUG com.DummyTest - x2: 4
10:03:10.588 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | request(1)
10:03:10.588 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | onNext(4)
10:03:12.600 [parallel-3] DEBUG com.DummyTest - x2: 6
10:03:12.600 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | request(1)
10:03:12.600 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | onNext(5)
10:03:12.600 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | cancel()
10:03:14.607 [parallel-4] DEBUG com.DummyTest - x2: 8
10:03:14.607 [parallel-4] INFO reactor.Flux.Generate.1 - | request(1)
10:03:16.618 [parallel-1] DEBUG com.DummyTest - x2: 10
```

Everything looks fine except for the first lines on the main thread. I was expecting the limitRate operator to make a request(1) then wait for the concatMap to finish and repeat, which is what we see in the later lines. However **two** request(1) are made and emitted immediately upon subscription! This is a problem for my actual use case! Can anyone explain why this is happening? Many thanks.

Comment: I do not really understand your problem : limitRate only serve to ensure requests will be done one by one, which is the case. Also, limitRate does **not** enforce any sequential/synchronous behavior. By essence, a Flux is sequential (items are emitted one by one). Now, their **ordering** is defined by the flux source and intermediate operations used. In your case, as you are using concatMap, your elements are processed in the order the datasource send them. Moreover, as your logs show the expected sequence of values, I do not understand what is your current problem.